# All IBOutlets and IBActions are gone from Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, interface-builder, iboutlet

I have a big project where ALL IBOutlets and IBActions are suddenly showing as not existing anymore in Interface Builder. They're still hooked up, and the project builds and runs just fine, and the source files shows them as connected, but I can't modify or add any new ones in Interface Builder. All object classes have been set correctly, and it just suddenly started happening here now.

I cleaned the build dir, deleted derived data, and even tried with the beta of Xcode 6.2 (running 6.1.1 now), but it still doesn't show any new outlets and complains the existing ones don't exist.

This has happened with every XIB in the project. Other projects seem to be fine.

[image: xib on the left, class source on the right]

EDIT: To make it even worse, it seems I can't set a new class for an object. Tried adding a UIView, then changing it to a custom UIView subclass I just created, but when I run it I get "Unknown class BubbleView in Interface Builder file."

EDIT 2: Seems I had to set the module in IB for the new class, but I have never had to do that before. Haven't changed or added any modules either. Was hoping there was a fix now and I tried setting the module for the objects that complained about missing outlets/actions, but that didn't help. This is just getting stranger and stranger.